# Create a new table with a relation in the Database, with Doctrine in Symfony

Tags: php, database, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm struggling with this, in my project in symfony. I have a entity content, with doctrine  i have a table in my db content, that saves contents. Every content has an id. If anyone wants to see a specific content they have to request it by **submitting an email**, I need to associate **all the emails** to the ***specific id content***. I dont want to create a new entity just to save the request emails. Is there a way to create/associate a new table with doctrine annotations. They have to be in a relation **many-to-one**. Or is there another simple way to save the email requests.  This is the code I have, but is not working.

```
    /**         
     * @ORM\Table(name="content")
     * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="myBundle\Repository\ContentRepository")
     */
    class Content{
        /**
         * @var integer
         * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
         */
        private $id;

        /**
         * @var string $nome
         * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Content")
         * @ORM\Column(name="email_request", type="string", length=255, unique=false, nullable=false )
         */
        private $emailRequest;
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: What do you mean by 'not working'? Can you share some errors or ways you've tried to run it? If you're talking about many-to-one relationship, there must be also second entity... could you post it?

Also - if you have already created the model in php, there's simple way for doctrine to create required tables in `symfony`. Just call `app/console doctrine:schema:update --force` from terminal while in main folder on your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$emailRequest` wouldn't be defined as Column if you want it to map entity. You need to define `@ORM\JoinColumn` instead.